# InvalidArgumentError assertion failed: [predictions must be >= 0] [Condition x >= y did not hold element-wise:] AUC metric only

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am training a MLP with tensorflow on mixed data (string and numeric), and it works fine with all .csv files under study but one. With that one, the network training works only if AUC is not added to the model metrics, but fail otherwise, complaining:

```
InvalidArgumentError
 assertion failed: [predictions must be >= 0] [Condition x >= y did not hold element-wise:] [x (functional_5/sequential/dense_4/Sigmoid:0) = ] [[-nan][-nan][-nan]...] [y (Cast_6/x:0) = ] [0]
     [[{{node assert_greater_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/else/_1/assert_greater_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_2207]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

I have googled the issue and most answers blame the difference between the model output layer shape and labels shape, but in my case they are equals and the rest of shapes match (as a matter of fact, the training works perfectly without the AUC metric and with other datasets).

I think the problem must be in the data, but I have deeply verified that it is substantially equal to others: same column types, same dimensions. There must be some detail making keras struggle with the computation of AUC scores, but I don't know what it can possibliy be. Any ideas? Many thanks in advance!

```
Keras 2.4.3
tensorflow 2.3
Python 3.7
```

Comment: People are not going to be able to solve this without being able to reproduce your issue. Please take a look at the guidelines for asking a question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and make sure that you post a minimal reproducible code that produces the same error.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66373379/14290681) answers your query?